# How to Exclude File Types from Download in MS Code

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a setting or a way to exclude certain file types/extensions from downloading in MS Visual Studio Code?

I want to exclude .txt and .xml files.

Looking at the preference settings and running numerous Google searches.